# How I can pinch zoom UIImage without using UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have UIImage and I want  to scale it without setting it into UIImageView.
How I can do that ?

Comment: How are you drawing the `UIImage` now? Any interaction with the user should be handled by a `UI` element with which the user can interact. An `UIImage` is, although the name suggest other which, not a `UI` element. You need to display it in `UIImageView`, `UIButton`, ... `

Answer (score 1):

As @rckoenes mentioned, UIImage is simply an image object, it does not handle display, which is precisely what UIImageView is for.

For pinch zooming an image, the easiest way is to add a [UIImageView as a subview to a UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866086/how-to-implement-pinch-in-pinch-out-in-uiimageview-which-is-inside-uiscrollview).

Answer (score 0):

If what you wanted was to change the size of your UIImage, I answered this here: [set size of an image programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831332/set-size-of-an-image-programatically/19831523#19831523)

Simply do this:

```
// Given a UIImage image and a CGSize newSize:

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Your scaled image is now in newImage
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But here we should define the newSize is there a possibility to do something like when using "CGAffineTransformScale".I mean the pinch zoom is doing dynamically?